# Is the design of most public and office bathrooms badly defective from a sanitation perspective?

Tags: sanitation

The vast majority of public, business, and office bathrooms that I see follow the same formula:

- No toilet seat lid covers
- Power flush
- Individual stalls with closeable door; hand-washing outside the stalls

Based on what I've read, I have identified numerous critical sanitation flaws with this design.

The first obvious problem is the lack of toilet seat lid covers. Flushing without the cover on can produce a disgusting aerosol that's literally full of crap and possibly infectious. There's even an academic journal article detailing this phenomenon (see https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4692156/).

A lot of public/business/office use bathrooms have exceptionally powerful flush, which would intuitively cause a larger aerosol.

The next major and obvious problem is that the user is not given the chance to wash hands in the bathroom stall. This presents 2 significant consequences: #1 users have to pull their pants up or put their clothes back on normally **without washing their hands**, so their clothes become potentially contaminated, and #2 the stall door handle/lock-unlock mechanism also gets contaminated in the same way.

Are these legitimate concerns - or exaggeration bordering on paranoia?

Comment: The most obvious problem is missing.  After being as careful as possible and thoroughly washing one's hands, the exit door is more often a "pull", that requires contaminating one's hands in order to get out.

Comment: I agree with @RayButterworth that the inability to exit the bathroom without touching a highly contaminated handle is the biggest problem. However, I believe your observations are valid. But... toilet paper is your friend (as are paper towels.)

Comment: @anongoodnurse I am confused by your *"toilet paper us your friend"* comment. How is toilet paper going to deal with the issues the OP raises? Especially pulling pants up.

Comment: With respect, regarding pulling pants up etc., are you looking to bathe every time you use the toilet? Your rear is not washed thoroughly, so in my view your concern for your clothing is not going to stand up to scrutiny. As for the stall door handle, if you wash your hands before leaving, this shouldn't pose a problem either. The only issue I see is with those who **don't** wash their hands and leave via a door described by @RayButterworth thereby making everyone else re-contaminate their hands with their bacteria.

Comment: @ChrisRogers, I think the "*toilet paper is your friend*" refers to the practice of holding toilet paper (or paper towel) in your hand after washing in order to open the door without directly touching the handle.

Comment: Ah I see @RayButterworth that is a good point